# Local mathjax with mkdocs

Tags: javascript, python, mathjax, mkdocs

I'd like to use MathJax with Mkdocs on a computer which does not have access to the internet, I can't therefore just call the Mathjax CDN.

**Config**

`mkdocs.yml`:

```
site_name: My Docs

extra_javascript:
  - 'javascripts/MathJax-2.7.5/MathJax.js'
  - 'javascripts/MathJax-2.7.5/extensions/MathMenu.js'

markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.arithmatex
```

**File structure**

```
project/
    docs/
        javascripts/
            MathJax-2.7.5/
                ...
    mkdocs.yml
```

Following [Mathjax's documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html#obtaining-mathjax-via-an-archive), the folder `/MathJax-2.7.5/` contains the whole uncompressed archive.

**Problem**

Running `mkdocs serve` I get the following errors:

```
[E 181003 11:32:04 web:1591] Uncaught exception GET /javascripts/MathJax-2.7.5/extensions/MathMenu.js (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8000', method='GET', uri='/javascripts/MathJax-2.7.5/extensions/MathMenu.js', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Host': '127.0.0.1:8000', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36', 'Dnt': '1', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Referer': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1512, in _execute
        result = yield result
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2422, in get
        yield self.flush()
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 947, in flush
        start_line, self._headers, chunk, callback=callback)
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 400, in write_headers
        data += self._format_chunk(chunk)
      File "/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 412, in _format_chunk
        "Tried to write more data than Content-Length")
    tornado.httputil.HTTPOutputError: Tried to write more data than Content-Length
[E 181003 11:32:04 web:1016] Cannot send error response after headers written
```

These 2 errors occur repeatedly until I stop the server.

---

Using `--no-livereload` prevents the issue, the server returns:

```
INFO    -  Building documentation...
INFO    -  Cleaning site directory
INFO    -  Building documentation to directory: /var/folders/qw/6ccdf6w14k354611cpl0x99h0000gn/T/tmpqlulnc9t
INFO    -  Running at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
INFO    -  Hold ctrl+c to quit.
```

But the math don't render:

```
$$
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}
$$
```

[image: not rendered maths]

Comment: `--no-livereload` causes MkDocs to use a different server which probably handles the same error in a different way. You say the math doesn't render. Why not? What errors are reported by your browser?

Comment: I found [this bug report](https://github.com/lepture/python-livereload/issues/174) which may be relevant. Unfortunately there is not enough information to know for sure. And I'm not sure if that is a bug in Livereload or Tornado. If a bug in Tornado, then it would effect both of the servers.

Comment: There is no error logged in the browser console ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. I would suggest reaching out to the  developer of `pymdownx.arithmatex`. I know that he uses the extension with MkDocs and he would likely be in a better position to help.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: [Use a single file bundled MathJax instead](https://github.com/pkra/MathJax-single-file).

For your case, I've seen the math render with [this bundled](https://github.com/pkra/MathJax-single-file/blob/master/dist/TeXSVGTeX/MathJax.min.js). [Working example](https://mathjax-single-file.netlify.com/)

---

I thought this'd be easy, just either (a) modify mkdocs static server setting or (b) just bundle Mathjax altogether into 1 single .js file, webpack style.

For option (a), `mkdocs` doesn't provide that much customization for its static server...

Then I spent a long time on (b). Mathjax makes ajax call to load its extensions and file on its own, so it's incredibly difficult to bundle the whole thing together.

Just as I was about to try serving Mathjax statically on another local server, I found this [article](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/wiki/Single-file-built) in Mathjax wiki, checkout the repo, load up one of the dist file and boom, it just works. Be sure to go over to that repo and give it a star!

Here's a [working example](https://mathjax-single-file.netlify.com/) with your string. The mathjax bundle is pretty large (1.9mb) so it'll take a while to load.