# Unable to render latex equations in .md files on mkdocs with mathjax support

Tags: markdown, mathjax, mkdocs

I followed the instructions I could find online such as in this [link](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/math/) or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882261/mkdocs-and-mathjax) but I could not render latex formula within my mkdocs website. I also tried to download mathjax and install it locally but to no avail. I tried markdown extensions such as mdx_math or arithmatex.

When I host my website locally with `mkdocs serve` no errors appear so I don't know how to debug.

Since most of the tutorials I found seem to date a bit, is MathJax still the way to go ? I did not find any promising other solutions. And how can I obtain more details while debugging mkdocs ?

Comment: maybe look for errors in your browser's developer tools, e.g. for firefox: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/index.html

Comment: Indeed it helped, I got this error:
`Loading failed for the <script> with source https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML`
I think my company's network is preventing the connection to this site somehow

Answer (score 2):

It seems I can't access the sites for MathJax through my company's network. I ended up following the instructions given here [Local mathjax with mkdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624102/local-mathjax-with-mkdocs?rq=2) to generate a single file for MathJax, it's the only thing that worked.